# Unset a specific session using session id

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I am the administrator of the site. I want unset a particular session, and I know its session id.

The users are just starting the session like this:

```
session_id("usernumber");
session_start();
```

Let’s say user A has usernumber "123".

I want to destroy all the values of the user A. User A will not regenerate the sessio_id() after setting that as `session_id("123");`.

How can I unset destroy only for user A?

Comment: A quick look into the docs reveals: [`session_unset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.session-unset.php).

Comment: witch way users logs on? or its just open site with session handler?

Comment: This comment could help you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#95809

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without reverse enginering the session handler....

```
<?php

session_id($_GET['killsid']);
session_start();
session_destroy() || die "failed to kill";
```

Comment: Worked fine. Although, code by @Hardik Sondagar is better for safe implementation.

Answer (score 13):

[Answer by Jack Luo on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#114709)

```
$session_id_to_destroy = 'nill2if998vhplq9f3pj08vjb1';
// 1. commit session if it's started.
if (session_id()) {
    session_commit();
}

// 2. store current session id
session_start();
$current_session_id = session_id();
session_commit();

// 3. hijack then destroy session specified.
session_id($session_id_to_destroy);
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_commit();

// 4. restore current session id. If don't restore it, your current session will refer     to the session you just destroyed!
session_id($current_session_id);
session_start();
session_commit();
```

Comment: This one is excellent. Exactly what I was looking for so you can kick other people off system.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to get session_save_path() (in this directory session files are stored).
When you are using default session names the filename looks like sess_jgimlf5edugvdtlaisumq0ham5 where jgimlf5edugvdtlaisumq0ham5 is user session id so you can just unlink this file unless you dont have permissions to edit those files.

Comment: Works! 

public function drop_session($session_id) {
        unlink(session_save_path() . '/sess_' . $session_id);
    }

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! It doesn't require starting sessions. plain and simple! `+1`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only supported way to do so with the default session handler is to impersonate the user with `session_id("usernumber");` and then remove the values.

You could also [store sessions in a database](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php), which would make this all pretty straightforward, yet you need to write your own session handling code.

BTW, the session ID is supposed to be a long random string which you cannot guess. Using `123` means that any anonymous visitor can easily log in with any user credentials.