# Can you kill particular sessions?

Tags: php, session, server-side, sessionid

I have a shopping cart which uses sessions for the basket.  I am also using a finance company as a payment option.  The finance company processes the order then sends a HTTP POST response to my server. The order_id and session_id will be returned in that HTTP response. Also the session_id is specified before the user is directed to the finance payment system.

Is there a way I can destroy that session using the returned SESSION_ID

Many Thanks,

Peter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unset a specefic session using session id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703842/unset-a-specefic-session-using-session-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_id($_GET['killsid']);
session_start();
sesstion_destroy() || die "failed to kill";
```

Comment: In the future, rather than copying the answer form a duplicate question, leave a comment stating that it's duplicate with a link (or, if you have the privilege, vote to close).