# How can I unset the session of a specific user?

Tags: php, security, session

I have a session like this `$_SESSION['login']` and when it is equal with `1`, it means the use is logged into my website:

```
if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
    // You are logged
} else {
    // login/register
}
```

Also I have another session which contains user's id. Something like this:

```
echo $_SESSION["Id"]; 
/* It is containing the user's id (an integer number).
   Something like: 234124
*/
```

Now I want to unset `$_SESSION['login']` for the user who has a specific id. For example I want to `unset($_SESSION['login'])` for `$_SESSION["Id"] = 234124`. How can I do that?

---

**Edit:** All I'm trying to do: When an user changes his password, I remove all his cookies from `cookies` table to sign him out from all his other devices. Also I want to remove his session.

Comment: session_start(); session_destroy(); the whole session you previously created will destroyed.

Comment: My question asks: how can I do that for an specific user?

Comment: oh right @stack I misunderstood question.

Comment: I don't know enough to be 100% sure about it but I'm pretty sure you would'nt be able to unset the session for a particular user you would have to redirect that user to a page which unset their session; as the session is stored locally rather than in a database; however I could be totally wrong.

Comment: Can't see the point of having a session login and id, you can just unset the session id to log him out.

Comment: Are you trying to unset one user's session while handling http requests of another user?  Or are you trying to destroy the current user's session?

Comment: use reverse enginering if you have the session id. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703842/unset-a-specefic-session-using-session-id

Comment: @BeetleJuice The first one

Comment: is there multiple user logged in option like anything? one browser create session for one user right? am i wrong?

Comment: @stack I wrote an answer, but... why? Why would you want one user to be able to mess with another's session?

Comment: @BeetleJuice When an user changes his password, I need to logout his account from all other his devices.

Comment: @stack Ok I see. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Updated Answer

You've provided helpful details in your comments:

> When an user changes his password, I need to logout his account from
>   all other his devices.

Your question is essentially how to implement single login/logout across devices if you're using sessions.

Here is a simple approach:

1. User logs in, you set `userID` and `lastSeen` in session. `lastSeen` holds a timestamp.  Save no info in session that the user can change.
2. User logs into another device, you set `userID` and `lastSeen` in that session
3. Sessions across devices are always in sync (except for `lastSeen`) because they only hold non-changing data (userID, userName)
4. In your DB, have a `logout` table with columns `userID` `requestTime`
5. If a user logs out, changes her password or does anything else that should require a re-login, call `session_destroy()` and add an entry in `logout` table
6. When user tries to access restricted page, you check:

   - Does `$_SESSION['userID']` exist (means user logged in at some point)
   - Is `lastSeen` within the last 30 minutes (otherwise, call `session_destroy()` and request another login)
   - Is there a logout request with the user's ID in `logout` and with `requestTime > lastSeen` (means since we last saw the user, she requested to be logged out from another device). If so, `session_destroy()` and require another login.

## Original Answer

Sessions are handled in isolation. When a request arrives, the `$_SESSION` data for just that user is loaded in memory. So if userID 5 makes a request, you do not have access to the session data for user 7 (without some hacks).

If you want to unset the current user's session, whoever that user may be, you can do one of the following:

```
session_destroy(); //clears everything for the current user
unset($_SESSION['login']);// clears just this variable for the current user
```

If from one user's browsing session, you want to mess with another user: I don't see the use case. Sounds like it would have negative security implications, and it makes me question your greater architecture. It defeats the whole purpose of sessions: to provide each user an isolated, persistent storage locker on the server.

Anyway, to change a random user's session data from another user's browsing activity (again, why?), use a database to save and retrieve values instead. A table could be as simple as:

```
userID | sessionData | sessionExpires
```

You could store session data in JSON with `json_encode` and retrieve it with `json_decode` for any specific user, from any browsing session.

Comment: Thank you, upvote .. btw your activity is odd on the SO .. You had less than 2k rep just a few weeks ago, I mean you've earned lots of reputation recently . Why? Has you been hired in SO `;-)`? What is your new motivation for being active in here?

Comment: @stack I wasn't hired. Are you hiring? My motivation is learning. I've found that having to solve problems quickly and having to explain the solutions clearly forces me to learn a lot, and to practice efficient coding.

Answer (score 2):

it will remove all session variables and destroy the all session you created.

```
<?php
//start session
session_start();
// remove all session variables
session_unset(); 
// destroy the session 
session_destroy(); 
?>
```

Comment: But the OP wants to target a specific user's session, by user ID. Not just the current user

Comment: then simply add the if condition which specifies the session variable.

Comment: i dont even understand why the session created like that?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
 if ( $_SESSION["Id"] == 234124 ) {
       session_destroy();   
       session_unset(); 
 }
} else {
  // login/register
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use    `session_destroy();`

It destroys all of the data associated with the current session. So only intended user's(who clicked logout or in your case who changed password) session data will be removed.

[Check this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to know more.

Comment: But the OP wants to target a specific user's session, by user ID. Not just the current user